# How to design a grid layout which will fit whole screen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I like to design a layout like in the image below. What would be the best way to design this layout, so the icon will be centered in the box and if we load it in big screen the whole screen should fit those 8 boxes?

[image]

Comment: How did you tried to make this simple layout?

Comment: I tried to use grid layout and relative layout with ImageView. But not getting the exact results. also in bigscreen its not fitting the whole screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example on how you might do that layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/middle_separator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/middle_separator"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stuff"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#220000" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stuff"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#440000" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stuff"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#660000" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stuff"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/middle_separator"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#880000" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stuff"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#aa0000" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stuff"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#cc0000" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stuff"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ee0000" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stuff"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a bunch. works like a charm. except the <view> its not working . how to make that work? it says "Couldn't resolve resource"

Comment: @jquery404 It's a `<View />` tag (with a capital letter) and not `<view />`.